# Java: make constants accessible anywhere

Tags: java, constants, global

I have a Java program that should read configuration parameters from file, Like this:

```
java -jar myapp.jar --config config.txt ...
```

Once loaded, these parameters do not change and should be accessible by any class in the program.

Is it possible to make these parameters accessible from any class *without* explicitly adding them as parameter to constructors and methods? For example, I would like to be able to do this:

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args){

        // This list should be visible by any class
        List<String> CONFIGS= readMyConfigsFromFile(args[0]);    
        ...
    }
}

public class MyClass(){
    public MyClass(){
        String thisConf= CONFIGS.get(0); // Do something with this conf param taken from Main.
        ...
    }
}

public class MyOtherClass(){
    public MyOtherClass(){
        String thisConf= CONFIGS.get(0); // Do something with this conf param taken from Main.
        ...
    }
}
...
```

Is this possible at all? And is it an advisable set up to do? If not, what is the recommended design to go about it?

(I have read similar questions but I'm still unsure if and how it is possible in the situation I described)

Comment: https://www.mkyong.com/java/java-properties-file-examples/

Comment: Yes. Make CONFIGS a static, preferrably final, field of a class. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html. This will make your code harder to unit test, though, and you'd better use dependency injection, or just pass it around in constructors.

Comment: @Jonathan Portorreal I don't think your link is relevant here. I know how to read the config file. The problem I have is how to make its content visible anywhere.

Comment: Alternatively you can provide system properties via "java -Dname=value". And then all your classes can use the System to retrieve those values.

Comment: You make properties visible anywhere by creating an object (possibly of type `Properties`) and storing a public reference to it in a well-known location, possibly via constructor injection, or in a static member of a configuration class, as others suggested. If the latter perhaps you make it accessible via a public getter method rather than a variable.

Answer (score 2):

You could use the Singleton pattern.

To model it, I assume you have 2 fields in your configuration: a String and an integer.

```
public class Config {
    private static Config INSTANCE;

    private final String field1;
    private final int field2;

    public Config(String field1, int field2) {
        this.field1 = field1;
        this.field2 = field2;
    }

    public String getField1() {
        return field1;
    }

    public int getField2() {
        return field2;
    }

    public static Config getInstance() {
        if (INSTANCE == null) {
            INSTANCE = loadInstance();
        }
        return INSTANCE;
    }

    private static Config loadInstance() {
        // read your config from properties
        String field1 = ...
        int field2 = ...
        return new Config(field1, field2);
    }
}
```

And then use `Config.getInstance()` everywhere you need to get that instance.

Please note that this implementation has a flaw: it may be initialized several times if `getInstance()` gets called from different theads.

Double-checked locking https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-checked_locking may be used to overcome this flaw if it is important to you to only initialize once.

Answer (score 1):

This solution, like others, would require a mock object to unit test. But I think it's best as it encapsulates the arguments in an immutable object.  This also makes thread-safety a non-issue. Use a [HashMap](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html) instead of an array to access these by key instead of index if you prefer:

```
 public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args){

       new CONFIG(readMyConfigsFromFile(args[0]).toArray());              
       ...
    }

    public static final class CONFIG {

       private final String[] args;

       private static final CONFIG instance;

       private CONFIG(String[] args) {
           this.args = args;
           instance = this;
       }

       public static CONFIG getInstance() {
          return CONFIG.instance;
       }

       public String[] getArgs(){
           return Arrays.copy(this.args, this.args.length);
       }

       public String getArg(int index) {
          return args[index];
       }

}
```

To get arguments:

```
Main.CONFIG.getArgs();
```

Answer (score 0):

"Is this possible at all?". Yes, it is. You can easily do it with the help of static in java

```
public class Config {
private static final List<String> config = new ArrayList<String>();

public static void addConfig(String value){
    config.add(value);
}

public static List<String> getConfig(){
    return config;
}
```

}

To add values to config you can do

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        //Read value from file here in some variable say configValue
        Config.addConfig(configValue);
}
```

To access config

```
public class MyOtherClass(){
    public MyOtherClass(){
        Config.getConfig().get(0); // Do something with this conf param taken from Main.
        ...
    }
}
```

Note above code is not thread safe. You can make it thread safe by adding synchronization concepts

Now "And is it an advisable set up to do?". It depends on your requirements. As you mentioned these values does not change runtime then you can use this. But is the requirement we need to enforce that these values "should not change" once initialized then answer will be different and you should use something like Singleton Pattern and modify to make sure you can only read and not write once the object is constructed. Also note that with static methods, like I suggested, testing becomes really hard.